# How to delete a field already filled in by clicking on a checkbox? (Angular)

Tags: html, angular, typescript, checkbox

Are you guys ok? In the photo below, when I click on the "I am Brazilian" checkbox, the field below filled with the "CPF" would completely not erase it. At the moment it only erases 1 digit which is the last one, how can I do it? Below is the html code.

[Photo Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbpZy.png)

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="personalData" [editable]="true">
 <form [formGroup]="personalData">
  <ng-template matStepLabel>{{'account.signUp.personalData' | translate }}</ng-template>
    <p class="stepper-title">{{'account.signUp.personalData' | translate }}</p>
                        <div class="wrapper-hint">
                            <input class="input" formControlName="name" [placeholder]="'account.signUp.fullName' | translate" required>
                            <div class="not-match absolute" *ngIf="this.personalData?.controls?.name?.invalid && this.personalData?.controls?.name?.value">
                                {{ 'account.signUp.hint.name' | translate }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="radio-group-signup">
                            <mat-checkbox formControlName="isBrazilian" [(ngModel)]="isBrazilianCheck" color="primary">
                                {{ 'account.signUp.brazilian' | translate }}
                            </mat-checkbox>
    
                            <mat-radio-group formControlName="person" selected>
                                <mat-radio-button *ngIf="isBrazilianCheck" class="small-label" [value]="true">{{ 'account.signUp.naturalPerson' | translate }}</mat-radio-button>
                                <mat-radio-button *ngIf="isBrazilianCheck" class="small-label" [value]="false">{{ 'account.signUp.legalEntity' | translate }}</mat-radio-button>
                            </mat-radio-group>
                        </div>
    
                        <div class="wrapper-hint">
                            <input matInput class="input" formControlName="cpg" [mask]="isBrazilianCheck ? (personalData?.value?.person ? '000.000.000-00' : '00.000.000/0000-00') : ''"
                                    [showMaskTyped]="true" [placeholder]="'account.signUp.insertPassport' | translate" required>
                            <div class="not-match absolute" *ngIf="(personalData?.controls?.cpg?.invalid && personalData?.controls?.cpg?.value)">
                                {{ 'account.signUp.hint.identification' | translate }}
                            </div>
```

Comment: **never**, **never** mix [(ngModel)] and formControlName in the same tag. Really I'm strange Angular don't give you an error. About your question, you can subscribe to valuechange of the control and use setValue to give a value to the form or use the event '(change)' to give a value, e.g. `<mat-checkbox formControlNme="isBrazilian" (change)="$event.checked && personalData.get('cpf').setValue(null)">`. The before condition only execute the setValue is the $event.checked is true

Comment: @Eliseo I just change one thing and did it works. Like this (change)=!$event.checked && personalData.get('cpg').setValue('')". Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the string with an empty one. At the place where you now have the code to remove the last digit.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Erik Leusink, don't have an variable with string empty :( I don't know how works this comportament.

Answer (score 0):

I created a method inside the component.ts and in the html I put it in the check-box container.

signup.component.ts

```
public clearInput(): void {
this.personalData.patchValue({cpg: ''});
```

signup.component.html

```
<mat-checkbox formControlName="isBrazilian" [(ngModel)]="isBrazilianCheck" color="primary" (change)="clearInput()">
                            {{ 'account.signUp.brazilian' | translate }}
                        </mat-checkbox>
```

That solved my case.